# Googlebot 404 crawl errors after website changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, googlebot

I had an old asp.net website (aspx) and have redesigned it with asp.net MVC using SSL.  Anyway, after I promoted the new site I saw a ton of errors which were being generated by bots looking for old pages; the errors were looking something like this: The controller for path '/blablabla/moreBlalbalba/page.aspx' was not found or does not implement IController. So, I updated my error handling to return a 301 response and redirect to the home page and added a sitemap.  The google 404 console errors went away for around a month, but now have a ton of 404 errors and they are all pointing to the old site structure.  As a side note, the new MVC/SSL site  has no 404 errors in the webmaster console, all the errors are on the non SSL site.  So, what is the best way to update the bots for the new site structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to redirect all traffic from HTTP to HTTPS, using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089/best-way-in-asp-net-to-force-https-for-an-entire-site). This may solve your problem already.

And secondly create a sitemap for Google to check the relevant pages of the website, [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45826388/i-use-asp-net-to-generate-a-sitemap-xml-get-google-webmaster-says-your-sitema/47635958#47635958)